# MSN Messenger/Growl Style Alerts in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, alerts

Does anyone know of any C++ Libraries which I can easily integrate in a project to allow me to show MSN Messenger/Outlook/Growl style toast popups?

Tried having a look and found lots of Visual Basic controls etc but nothing for C++ so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna a look at [Customizable Alert Window](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/dialog-basedapplications/article.php/c15569/) by Marius Bancila.

Answer (score 2):

How about... growl for windows? :]

http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/

Comment: That would work fine, but I wanted to have it self contained without needed Growl as a dependency.

Comment: Fair enough, makes life simpler! :]

Answer (score 0):

The VS 2008 MFC has a toast dialog that looks just like outlook toast. The disadvantage is that you have to have MFC as the main framework in you app - might not be worth it just for the toasts.

Create a sample MFC project in Visual Studio and see if it is at all suitable.